# calling base.OnCallStateChanged on overriding gets a no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, android

trying to implement a call detector on android using c#.
I want to implement my logic and then to call the base method.
When I use override, i get the "no suitable method found to override" error. Why is that?
Clearly there is a fitting method in the base class...

This is my code:

```
  public class DNDPhoneStateListener : PhoneStateListener  
    {                    
        public override void onCallStateChanged (CallState state, string incomingNumber) 
        {  
            // my logic  
            base.OnCallStateChanged (state, incomingNumber);  
        }  
    }
```

Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you check your formatting, as this is very hard to read and you will get less help as a result.

Comment: Thanks, sry about that.

Comment: Change the lowercase "o" in the method name to an uppercase "O"

Comment: OMG... That was it, i can't believe it... Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, I'll add it as a formal answer now :)

Comment: Is this Xamarin? If so it should be tagged as such. As for your error, this is a typical Java vs. C# type of error.

Answer (score 0):

onCallStateChanged should be OnCallStateChanged.

The error is informing you of this by essentially saying "there isn't a method in the base class with that signature".

This error can also come up if you try to override a method in an interface; there's nothing to override!